# How do I extract the parameters individually?

Tags: c#, nlog

How do I set up **NLog** to extract the parameters individually?
Expected parameters in the logging log:

- Date Time;
- Project name;
- Class name;
- Name of the method;
- Line number where the calling method of the logger is located;
- Lger's message.

My ultimate goal: I want to write the logger data to a **csv** file so that each parameter is recorded in a separate field.

**NLog.config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <!-- Log to a file -->
        <target name="console" xsi:type="Console"
                layout="${longdate}|${callsite}|${callsite-linenumber}|${message}"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <!-- All messages with a minimum log level of Debug or higher are written to the Console -->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Logger1**

```cs
namespace LoggingWriteJsonWinFrmQ1
{
    internal class Logger1
    {
        public void CreateLogger()
        {
            Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            log.Info("info message. Step-1");
            log.Info("info message. Step-2");
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm getting the result now:**

```
2024-02-28 22:21:36.6406|LoggingWriteJsonWinFrmQ1.Logger1.CreateLogger|17|info message. Step-1
2024-02-28 22:21:36.7066|LoggingWriteJsonWinFrmQ1.Logger1.CreateLogger|18|info message. Step-2
```

**I expect the result:**

```
2024-02-28 22:21:36.6406|LoggingWriteJsonWinFrmQ1|Logger1|CreateLogger|17|info message. Step-1
2024-02-28 22:21:36.7066|LoggingWriteJsonWinFrmQ1|Logger1|CreateLogger|18|info message. Step-2
```

---

## Update-1

**NLog.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="run_log"
                xsi:type="File"         
                fileName="${basedir}/Application.csv"
                keepFileOpen="true">
            <layout xsi:type="CSVLayout">
                <column name="DateTime" layout="${longdate}" />                 
                <column name="Project" layout="${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=false}" />
                <column name="Class" layout="${callsite:className=false:includeSourcePath=true}" />
                <column name="Method" layout="${callsite-linenumber}" />
                <column name="Message" layout="${message}" />               
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="run_log" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I get the result **Application.csv** (The fields are separated by dots)

```
DateTime,Project,Class,Method,Message
2024-02-29 21:17:39.8456,LogggingMainProjectTetst.Logger1.CreateLogger,CreateLogger,18,info message. Step-1
2024-02-29 21:17:41.4306,LogggingMainProjectTetst.Logger1.CreateLogger,CreateLogger,22,info message. Step-2
```

I expect the result **Application.csv** (The fields are separated by commas)

```
DateTime,Project,Class,Method,Message
2024-02-29 21:17:39.8456,LogggingMainProjectTetst,Logger1,CreateLogger,18,info message. Step-1
2024-02-29 21:17:41.4306,LogggingMainProjectTetst,Logger1,CreateLogger,22,info message. Step-2
```

Comment: Since your goal is CSV-output. Then maybe just apply NLog CsvLayout - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/CsvLayout#example

Comment: @Rolf Kristensen see **Update-1**

Comment: So you want the [${logger}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer)-output split into multiple values ? Right now NLog only supports `${logger:shortName=true}`. But you are wellcome to create pull-request to also support `${logger:property=NameSpace}`. Alternative you can create your own custom layout-renderer: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer